# Aligning transparent PNG with underlying elements

Tags: image, flutter

I have an image of a resistor with transparent regions where the color code goes. Behind the resistor I'm trying to position the colors so that I can generate any resistor combination.

[image: Transparent resistor]

I managed to get it right on my phone in portrait mode and it looks almost right in the browser when I resize it to a specific size:

[image: Resistor]

However, in landscape mode or in a larger browser window, the colors no longer align with the image:

[image: Colors not aligned]

I am using a stack for putting items on top of each other in Z-direction

```
  Stack(
    children: <Widget>[

      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: _rings,
      ),
      Image(image: AssetImage('assets/resistor.png')),
    ]
  ),
```

and I use an ugly combination of spacers and my own Ring implementation, which is basically a constrained box

```
_rings = [
  Spacer(flex: 10),
  Ring( _ringColors[0]),
  Spacer(flex: 1),
  Ring( _ringColors[1]),
  Spacer(flex: 1),
  Ring( _ringColors[2]),
  Spacer(flex: 14),
];
```

Ring:

```
return ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      minWidth: 40.0,
      minHeight: 100.0,
    ),
    child: Material(
      color: _ringColors[widget.colorIndex.value],
    ));
```

}

I don't see how this will be responsive for all orientations and sizes.

How would one typically approach this in Flutter?

Comment: IMO, the best (and possibly easiest) solution would be to just generate the image with the colors you want. So replace each of the 3 regions on your original image with unique colors that won't appear anywhere else in the image, then use the `image` library to replace each of those pixels with your intended color. Then you can just display the image as you normally would.

Comment: You should also probably try wrapping the `Ring` at the two ends of your list with `Expanded` providing the flex factor from your `Spacer`s on the ends of the list and removing those `Spacer`s.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore: phew, I wanted to avoid image manipulation. Because of the transparent shadow effect it's not just a single color to be replaced. But perhaps I could have 2 PNGs on top of each other. One in which I replace the color and the other for the effect... I'll go and learn about image manipulation in Dart/Flutter.

Comment: Seems like a good way to go. The [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package is the place to start. It'll allow you to decode the image and provide an array of pixel values that you can modify to add color. You'll probably have to reencode that pixel array to get data that you can pass to an `Image` widget constructor. I'll be around if you have any questions.

Comment: as simple as this: `child: Stack(
children: [
Image.asset('ring0.png', color: Colors.red,),
Image.asset('ring1.png', color: Colors.green,),
Image.asset('ring2.png', color: Colors.blue,),
Image.asset('resistor.png'),
],
),` - get `ring0.png` from [here](https://pasteboard.co/JXo7tD2.png) - `ring1.png` and `ring2.png` are created the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the advise of [@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) and created one image per ring in the same size as the original one.

[image: Overlay]

[image: Ring1]

[image: Ring2]

[image: Ring3]

I then stack 4 images on top of each other, each with a different [Color](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html), using [BlendMode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode-class.html) to exchange the non-transparent color by a given one.

```
  Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Image.asset("assets/ring1.png", color: Colors.yellow,),
      Image.asset("assets/ring2.png", color: Colors.purple,),
      Image.asset("assets/ring3.png", color: Colors.brown,),
      Image.asset("assets/resistor.png",),
    ]
  ),
```

For real resistor values based on an input value, the color needs to be dynamic, of course.

---

The approach suggested by [@Christopher Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13250142/christopher-moore) didn't work out for me, because I want compatibility for web. It may still be useful for someone. It uses the [image package](https://pub.dev/packages/image), for which I need I/O to get a `byte[]` which is then decoded as an image.

Reference in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dev_dependencies:
  image: ^3.0.2
```

Parts of the code (untested since I could not use `await` either, sorry):

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as png;
import 'dart:io';
...
var file = File('assets/colors.png');  // direct I/O not allowed in web
var bytes = await file.readAsBytes(); 
var image = png.decodeImage(bytes);
```

Comment: Just FYI you can get byte data from assets with `rootBundle.load('assets/colors.png')`